# SQL Query - Issues with Multiple ISNULL's and Calculations

Tags: sql

I've written this query that basically calculates future prices of items, kind of a 'What If' report. I've got a couple of issue though with the INSULLs last two calculations in the select command and I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong, below is the full query:

```
SELECT
    T1.[ItemCode],
    T2.[ItemName],
    T2.Cardcode, 
    T4.Price as 'Buying Price',
    T4.Currency as 'Buy Currency',
    isnull(T6.Rate,1) as 'Todays Exchange Rate (Buy)',
    ( ISNULL(T4.price,1)/ ISNULL (T6.Rate,1)) as 'Todays Buying Price',
    T0.Cardcode as 'Customer code',
    T0.[CardName] as 'Filler',
    T3.Price as 'Selling Price',
    T3.Currency as 'Sell Currency',
    isnull(T5.Rate,1) as 'Todays Exchange Rate (Sell)',
    (ISNULL(T3.price,1)/ ISNULL (T5.Rate,1)) as 'Todays Selling Price',
    (ISNULL(T3.price,1)/ ISNULL (T5.Rate,1))-(ISNULL(T4.price,1)/ ISNULL (T6.Rate,1))/( ISNULL(T3.price,1))*100) as 'Gross %',
    (((( ISNULL(T4.price,1)/ ISNULL (T6.Rate,1))+ T2.CstGrpCode)* T2.U_Shipping_Percent)/(( ISNULL(T3.price,1))/( ISNULL (T5.Rate,1))))) *100 as 'Net % exc. outbound cost'
FROM
    ORDR T0
    Inner join RDR1 T1 on T0.docentry = T1.docentry
    Inner join OITM T2 on T1.itemcode = T2.itemcode
    left outer join ITM1 T3 on T1.itemcode = T3.itemcode and T3.pricelist = 2
    left outer join ITM1 T4 on T1.itemcode = T4.itemcode and T4.pricelist = 1
    left outer join ORTT T5 on T3.Currency = T5.Currency and CONVERT(varchar(10), T5.RateDate, 102) = CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)
    left outer join ORTT T6 on T4.Currency = T6.Currency and CONVERT(varchar(10), T6.RateDate, 102) = CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)
Where
    T3.Price <> 0 and
    T4.Price <> 0       
Order by
    T0.DocEntry
```

This the error I'm getting on the last calculation of the select command:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any help would be great, I'm fairly sure I've got to many bracket (or too little) but I cannot seem to get the query to work.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What's the specific problem you have? ("It doesn't work" is not specific). If there's an error message, what's the specific error message? (With line number, and tell us the corresponding line number).  What does your table structure look like? What's some sample data? What do you expect the output to look like? What does the output actually look like? (All this information should be edited into your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the parens are unnecessary. I'm guessing you want (A-B)/C for the first one.

```
(ISNULL(T3.price,1) / ISNULL(T5.Rate,1) - ISNULL(T4.price,1) / ISNULL(T6.Rate,1)) /
    ISNULL(T3.price,1) / 100 as 'Gross %',
```

The second one is equivalent to this, I think (T4/T6 + T2) / (T3*T5):

```
(ISNULL(T4.price,1) / ISNULL(T6.Rate,1) + T2.CstGrpCode) * T2.U_Shipping_Percent) /
    ISNULL(T5.Rate,1) / ISNULL(T3.price,1) * 100
```

Comment: That seems to work for the first one, I also realised I'm missed a ',' at the end of the third line. Any ideas on the second one, this is the one really causing the problems.

Comment: Don't worry I've just solved it.

Comment: Well I'm curious now. I see similar ratios between the two but it was hard to guess was you intended.